# Load and parse remote page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am upgrading an old asp site to asp-mvc4. Because there will be a fair amount of style changes between old and new, as part of the process (prior to each page being fully converted) i want to effectively grab the generated html from an old page and parse out the header,footer etc to show the content of the page within a div on my page.

It appears that i am blocked from doing cross site requests via ajax, and whereas i could load the content into an iframe, i cannot see a way of then modifying the content in that iframe.
Is there a way around this apart from me copying each page manually?

Comment: I would do the whole manipulation once, on server side...

Comment: @Bartdude sounds like he wants to take a loot at each one first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you cannot load another domain page via ajax unless the domain has cors (Cross-origin resource sharing) support, asp.net mvc does not has the cors support out of the box, but it is not very complicated to implement one. Maybe this page should help https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs

Comment: very helpful, i changed the web.config on the asp server and i can now retrieve the page via a jQuery AJAX request. Only problem is all images with src like images/picture.jpg are missing the full path and thus try to resolve the image path locally. I need to somehow either set the default root for the requested content, or update all src's and hrefs which arent fully qualified paths to include http://www.thewebsitesroot.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file using `file_get_contents()`, filter out the part you want and echo it out.

Comment: is that a php command? i was hoping for a javascript solution

Comment: @Tim yes, it is indeed PHP.

Comment: thanks but this is an asp.net mvc upgrade.(im not a php programmer) :)